# How do I get internet on my server?

Tags: networking, server, internet

I'm a noob and I just installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on my computer. I can't use the internet connection! I'm connected to ethernet and I thought it would automatically get internet connection. I was wrong. I have no idea how to get it up and running. I know the smart people on here will know how to fix it. My network interfaces are `enp4s0` and `lo`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50388/discussion-on-question-by-ex-master-how-do-i-get-internet-on-my-server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use gedit, kate, nano, leafpad or any other text editor to set up `/etc/network/interfaces` something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here. I recommend that servers use a static IP address so that you can later find it with ssh and ftp.

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown enp4s0 && sudo ifup -v enp4s0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: When I typed the command it said Failed to bring up enp4s0.

Comment: and RNETLINK say File exists

Comment: also ifdown: interface enp4s0 not configured

Comment: Is 192.168.1.1 consistent with addresses in your network? Did you make the necessary adjustments to these details?

Comment: I know you said to, but I didn't because I didn't know what to change and what to change it to.

Comment: Please run again: `sudo dhclient enp4s0` and then: `ifconfig` What address did you get? I will edit my answer to suit the result.

Comment: I know 192.168.1.150 isn't taken. 192.168.1.1 is the address of the router. http://imgur.com/OZPNygn is screenshot of ip scanner

Comment: The ip i got was 192.168.1.200 if you still care.

Comment: Please try again, let it run to completion and give me the image: `sudo ifdown enp4s0 && sudo ifup -v enp4s0`

Comment: Just try the command again?

Comment: WAIT! I see a mistake. Sorry. The second line should also be enp4s0. I accidently typed the wrong thing. Editing now. Correct the file, please.

Comment: Actually, I didn't put the typo in my file. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: May I please see the terminal output? Also, may I safely assume there is no desktop environment and therefor Network Manager is not running and interfering?

Comment: I have two operating systems and I choose when I boot up. Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server (both 16.04). I am using Ubuntu Server and there is no desktop enviroment. A

Comment: Oops, accidently pressed enter. What I was going to say was my phone just died so I can't take more pictures for a bit.

Comment: A picture of my interfaces file. Sorry the quality is bad. I took it with my laptop camera. imgur.com/a/3Sp5L

Comment: Can you just make it so when I boot up it does `sudo dhclient -v enp4s0`?

Comment: That would be good enough.

Comment: What I also need to see, clearly, is the result of: `sudo ifdown enp4s0 && sudo ifup -v enp4s0` Thanks.